highlight.js with deno fresh not applying style
I'm trying to syntax highlight some code with highlight.js used with deno / fresh. My failed attempts are with the current versions of deno/fresh/highlight.js at august 7, 2024.
I'm working on Windows 10, from PowerShell, where I've installed Deno.
To create my project I follow these steps :

I go to a root folder:
cd (...)/deno_apps
I create a fresh project:

deno run -A -r https://fresh.deno.dev

I specify for the project the name code_highlighter
to the question "do you want to use a styling library?" I answer yes / tailwind.css
to the question "do you use Visual Studio Code?" I answer no (I'm using notepad++)
-> the project is created
I enter the folder of my project
cd code_highlighter
I download highlight.js
npm install highlight.js
-> highlight.js is installed.
I then edit code_highlighter/routes/index.ts as follows (the code is aimed to show both the source code highlighted, with colors and indentation, and the html string generated by highlight.js) :

° !!! please note the commented import on the default css style import from highlight.js
import { Head } from "$fresh/runtime.ts";
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core';
import cpp from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/cpp';
//import 'highlight.js/styles/default.css';

const createMarkup = (htmlString) => {
  return { __html: htmlString };
};

export default function Home() {
  const codeTxt = '#include <iostream>\nint main() {}';
  hljs.registerLanguage('cpp', cpp);  
  const highlightedCode = hljs.highlight(
    codeTxt,
    { language: 'cpp' }
  ).value;
  return (
    <div>
      <pre>
        <code dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup(highlightedCode)}>
        </code>
      </pre>
      <div>
          {highlightedCode}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


I launch the application with:
deno task start


as output I get:
#include <iostream>
int main() {}

<span class="hljs-meta">#<span class="hljs-keyword">include</span> <span class="hljs-string">&lt;iostream&gt;</span></span> <span class="hljs-function"><span class="hljs-type">int</span> <span class="hljs-title">main</span><span class="hljs-params">()</span> </span>{}

What I observe is :

the indentation is ok
it looks like highlight.js has done some job, putting tags, classes, and so on
I don't see color or style. I don't know what I'm missing.

if I uncomment the import of the default style from highlight.js :
import 'highlight.js/styles/default.css';

I get this error on the Powershell console :
Watcher File change detected! Restarting!
error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Expected ';', '}' or  at file:///C:/Users/crill/data/temp/deno_apps/code_highlighter/node_modules/.deno/highlight.js@11.10.0/node_modules/highlight.js/styles/default.css:1:5
pre code.hljs {
~~~~
const manifest = (await import(toFileUrl(join(dir, "fresh.gen.ts")).href))
^
at async dev (https://deno.land/x/fresh@1.6.8/src/dev/dev_command.ts:38:21)
at async file:///C:/Users/crill/data/temp/deno_apps/code_highlighter/dev.ts:8:1
Watcher Process failed. Restarting on file change...
What am I doing wrong? What should I do to see also the color in the highlighted code?

You can't import a .css file in ts like this. The ts compiler will self-destruct as you're seeing.
I got around this using this npm package:
https://github.com/GeoffSelby/tailwind-highlightjs
The only thing to note is that you'll have to edit tailwind.config.ts to import tailwind-highlightjs. I am using this for now:
import twHLJS from "tailwind-highlightjs";

...

plugins: [twHLJS]


Seems like its working fine.
